# ta.valuewhen calculation only one time for condition true (pinescript/tradingview)

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to write a StopLoss and TakeProfit script based on the lowest. When the condition "buy" is true the script should take the previous lowest as a StopLoss. The problem is that the script recalculate the lowest and the close price for the entire duration of "buy = true". I need the script calculate this value when condition is true, but only in the first bar.

```
rr = input(1.5, title="RISK & REWARD")

buy = rsi > rsiMA and (Greenbar1 and Greenbar2 == 1) and (vfi > vfima and vfima > 0)
loweststop = ta.lowest(close, 10)
longstopl = ta.valuewhen(buy, loweststop, 1)
longprice = ta.valuewhen(buy, close, 1)
longtakep = ((longprice - longstopl) * rr) + longprice
longclose = high >= longtakep or low <= longstopl
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean only the first time the script is triggered, then use **var boolean buy**.
If you mean only for the first tick in a bar, then use **varip boolean buy**